# How to set http2-max-streams-per-connection with Kops

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kops

Is it possible to set the `--http2-max-streams-per-connection` value for a cluster created by Kops.

I have an interesting situation where one of my nodes falls into a `NotReady` status whenever I deploy a helm chart to it and I feel like it might be connected to this setting.

The nodes are generally fine and run without any issues, but once I deploy my helm chart, the status of whatever node it gets deployed to changes after a few minutes to `NotReady` Which I find weird.

I've done a bit of reading and seen a number of similar issues pointing to the setting `--http2-max-streams-per-connection` but I'm not how to go about setting this.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set this by adding the following to the cluster spec:

```
spec:
  kubeAPIServer:
    http2MaxStreamsPerConnection: <value>
```

See https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/kops/pkg/apis/kops#KubeAPIServerConfig and https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/cluster_spec/

That being said, I do not believe the reason for your `NotReady` nodes is due to that setting. You may want to join #kops-users on the kubernetes slack space and ask for help triaging that problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ole. Much appreciated.